# Скрипт не вешает куку php

Tags: php, request

Ребят скажите почему невешает куку

Вызываю так

```
URL::userTypeCookie (URL::userXss ($_POST['login']), $_POST['password']);
```

функция вот

```
static public function userTypeCookie ($userLogin = null, $userPass = null) {
if (($userLogin) && ($userPass)) {
setcookie ('userLogin', $userLogin, time () + 3600 * 24 * 7);
setcookie ('userPass', md5 (md5 ($userPass)), time () + 3600 * 24 * 7);
AUTH::userErrorMessage(2);
} else {
setcookie ('userLogin', '', time () - 3600 * 24 * 31);
setcookie ('userPass', '', time () - 3600 * 24 * 31);
header ('Location: .');
}
}
```

Comment: @nikoly0072, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего из-за вызова

```
header ('Location: .');
```

Он отправляет первый заголовок, после которого сразу происходит перезагрузка страницы. Загрузки страницы, в которой вы ставили куки, не происходит.

Да, и воспользуйтесь советом [[@Construct](/users/4463/construct)](/users/4463/construct) - отформатируйте текст